# Java - 'continue' loop iteration after certain timeout period

Tags: java, android, for-loop

Is there a way to exit ('continue;') a loop iteration after a certain timeout period?

I have a loop that will run gathering data from the web and then use this data to make a calculation.

The data become obsolete after about 1 to 2 seconds so if the loop iteration takes longer than 1 second then i want it to 'continue' to the next iteration.

Sometimes gathering the data can take time but sometimes the calculation can take longer than 1 second so a HTTP timeout won't work for what i need.
Also, while doing the calculation the thread i am using is blocked so i cannot check System.currentTimeMillis();

Is there a way to use another Thread to check the time and force the original for loop to continue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am answering this based on the assumption it is impossible to change the calculation code to check for a flag such as `boolean stop` or `System.currentTimeMillis()`. If this is to be true, then this is a possible solution.

What you'll need to do is spawn a new calculation each time you expect a new result. This program I've included does have some issues such as never assuring that the calculation ever finishes resulting in an infinite number of threads. Again, this is based on the assumption you have no way to stop the calculation prematurely. If you did have that option you can set a flag in the calculation loop to prematurely exit the method.

**I have no idea why I can't get the code styling to work correctly, I'm new to this site any help would be appreciated**

You will maintain a stack of results that have been processed. If you always obtain the top result, it will be the latest result you can possibly process at that point in time. The reason I have created a stack here instead of just over writing the previous result is incase you need to do something with previous calculation.

The body of `performCalculation` in my example is only important to simulate the environment you have mentioned.

You can create a new thread, or use the existing to continually process the results thrown into `results`.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Main
{
    private static int CALCULATION_THRESHOLD = 2000;

    private static Stack<Object> results = new Stack<Object>();

    private static Object resultTrigger = new Object();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Timer calculationTimer = new Timer(true);
        calculationTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                Thread calculationThread = new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                        Object result = performCalculation();
                        results.push(result);
                        synchronized(resultTrigger) {
                            resultTrigger.notifyAll();
                        }       
                    }
                };
                calculationThread.start();
            }
        }, CALCULATION_THRESHOLD, CALCULATION_THRESHOLD);

        synchronized(resultTrigger) {
            if (results.isEmpty()) {
                // This is bad as it will never end if you don't
                // get a result, add a timeout here. 
                try { resultTrigger.wait(); }
                catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
            }
        }

        // Get the next result
        Object result = results.pop();

        System.out.println ("Latest result is : " + result);

        // Do something with the remaining results or throw 
        // them away
        results.clear();
    }

    private static AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

    // This is the method we are assuming can't be
    // changed to check for a stop flag.
    public static Object performCalculation()
    {
        int calcID = counter.addAndGet(1);
        System.out.println ("Calculation " + calcID + " is running.");
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        int sleep = randomGenerator.nextInt(10000);
        // Ensure we sleep for at least 2 seconds
        try { Thread.sleep(sleep + 2000);   }
        catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
        return String.valueOf(counter.get());
    }
}
```

Output of Example:

### Run 1

Calculation 1 is running.
Calculation 2 is running.
Calculation 3 is running.
Latest result is : 3

### Run 2

Calculation 1 is running.
Calculation 2 is running.
Calculation 3 is running.
Calculation 4 is running.
Calculation 5 is running.
Latest result is : 5

### Run 3

Calculation 1 is running.
Calculation 2 is running.
Latest result is : 2

Comment: Seeing as I can't comment on anyone else's answers at the moment, AsychTask would be great, however it relies on being able to check for isCancelled within the calculation thread. I am reading this question to assume this cannot be done per this statement "Also, while doing the calculation the thread i am using is blocked so i cannot check System.currentTimeMillis();" cancel(true) on a AsyncTask does not automagically cancel a thread without the user checking the flag isCancelled().

Comment: +1 for a nice and long first answer.  I hope you get points soon enough so that you can comment, upvote, downvote etc. :)

Comment: Finnell: that said the answer suggesting to use an *AsyncTask* is better :)

Comment: @SpoonBender AysncTask would be better if he is able to check the isCancelled flag. If the calculation ran inside the AsyncTask _blocks_ for 15 seconds, it will not be canceled when AsyncTask.cancel(true). If for some reason, which I doubt, AsyncTask.cancel attempts to abort() the thread, that is horrible. If it attempts to interrupt the thread, it still isn't guranteed to stop the thread. An example would be running while(true) { } inside the AsyncTask execute. There is no way to stop it that doesn't invole doing something very bad like aborting a thread.

Comment: Thanks Andrew,All your assumptions are correct. the 'calculation' is done in a external Jar so i have no way of checking what is causing the slow calculation on some occasions let alone stopping it half way through.

Answer (score 4):

Use an `AsyncTask` to do your blocking calculation, and have a `Handler` belonging to your main thread.

In your `onPreExecute()` you can `Handler.postDelayed()` a `Runnable` which calls `AsyncTask.cancel(true)`. In your `onPostExecute()` you can cancel the aforementioned `Runnable` since it won't be needed if the calculation completes in time. Job done.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the easiest solution is to add System.currentTimeMillis() to calculation itself and if it detects that it is running too long to exit without result. When thread is unblocked you will have to check if there is a result and if not to "continue".
Of course, you can use another thread but that will be an overkill.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a `Callable` task submitted to an `ExecutorService` and run it with a time-out. The code should be pretty intuitive:

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;

class InterruptibleProcessing{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

        //the loop
        for(int i=0; i<iterations; i++){
            //run your data gathering process in a separate thread
            Future<Result> futureResult = es.submit(new Callable<Result>(){
                public Result call(){
                    //do you work here and return the result
                    return gatherData();
                }
            });

            try{
                //wait for result with timeout
                Result result = futureResult.get(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                //if we are here then we have the result in less than 1 second
                // do something and exit the loop
                break;
            }catch(TimeoutException timeout){
                //Didn't finish in time, cancel the task, and proceed to
                //next iteration. This will send an interrupt signal to 
                //your task thread.
                futureResult.cancel(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For this to work perfectly, your data gathering task will need to check for thread interrupts. This mainly includes:

1) Checking for thread interrupts inside loops that may use CPU for long time (this does not include I/O). If you have large loops doing heavy processing make sure you have this code run at relatively short intervals

```
if(Thread.isInterrupted()){
    throw new InterruptedException();
    //or maybe some other code to stop processing
}
```

2) Places that do I/O, like reading/writing from sockets or files usually check for interruption and throw some kind of exception. The kind of exception may be `InterruptedIOException`, `ClosedByInterruptException` and so on. The type of exception thrown is usually specified in the API of the corresponding blocking method. Methods that block on Java locks (like Queue.take(), etc.) will throw an `InterruptedException`.